# Scanning through large text corpus counting phrases in vocabulary

Tags: python, mysql, text-mining

I need to scan a corpus of around 1.5 million text documents and match any set of words, of length between 1 and 4, against a vocabulary of around 1.8 million phrases.

Extracting the word n-grams from each text file is not a problem, and is quite fast; the bottleneck is in the check against the vocabulary.

My vocabulary is stored in a MySQL table, properly indexed, and I'm querying each phrase like this:

```
SELECT (1) FROM vocab WHERE phrase=%s;
```

The whole thing runs veeery slowly. Any optimization ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you could have the entire vocabulary in the memory, couldn't you?

Comment: Do you have an index on `vocab(phrase)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to read in the entire vocabulary into memory once, and then you'll be able to run some queries on it pretty quickly. You could throw it in a `set` or a `dict`, or if you're feeling fancy you could even use a bloom filter to check for inclusion. I'm biased on this point, but I recommend [pybloomfiltermmap](https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap) if you choose to go that route.

If you use a bloom filter, one advantage is that it's much more compact than having to store a `set` in memory and they're quite fast. They do have bounds on the false-positive rate and in practice can be controlled to acceptable levels.

Comment: Cool! Putting it in memory worked, but I like this Bloom filters thing! Will dig deeper...